# WindowAdapter to dispatch a window event (closing window)

Tags: java, swing

I have created a class that extends from WindowAdapter so that every time I want to close a window, it asks you if you really want to close the window. The problem comes when I click "No". How can I handle it so that the window event doesn't "remain" there and the frame keeps trying to dispatch it?
I only do a return, and I can't come up with anything. Here's the code:

```
public class ExitController extends WindowAdapter{

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure to close this window?", 
        "Really Closing?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) 
        == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you do here should work. Other listeners would receive the event as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/).

It gives some basic code for this. The basic code would set the default close operation of the frame to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`.

Then in the WindowListener when the user confirms the close it will reset the default close operation to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` instead of using System.exit(0);

You can also use the `CloseListener` class which is a more complex version (because it provides more functionality) of youe ExitController class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `JFrame.processWindowEvent`:

```
protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) {
    super.processWindowEvent(e);  // --> this will call your listener

    if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
        switch(defaultCloseOperation) {
          case HIDE_ON_CLOSE:
             setVisible(false);
             break;
          case DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE:
             dispose();
             break;
          case DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE:
             default:
             break;
          case EXIT_ON_CLOSE:
              // This needs to match the checkExit call in
              // setDefaultCloseOperation
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Independently of what your listener does, the `JFrame` evaluates its `defaultCloseOperation` and closes or hides itself.

Therefore you need also to initialize the right default close operation of the frame on which you install your listener to prevent the default operation:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new ExitController ());
```

You could provide a method in `ExitListener`to facilitate this:

```
public class ExitController extends WindowAdapter {
     public void installOn(JFrame frame) {
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.addWindowListener(this);
     }
```

Comment: I have already done that. The problem really is that, when I interact with the interface and the panels change, the return call goes through all of them and keeps showing the confirm dialog (new pop-ups), as trying to dispatch the same (window) event. Is there any way to consume it or something?

Comment: @Jari you should add a small example program to your question which demonstrates the effect...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work ...  It says "The method consume() from the type AWTEvent is not visible".